# Whitespaces in Java/PHP

Tags: java, php, sql

Spaces not changing to underscored when sent from Java-->PHP-->SQL

Java code:

```
String urlString = "http://www.mysite.com/auth/verifyuser.php?name="+name.toLowerCase().replace(" ","_");
```

PHP code:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
$query = "select * from authinfo where name LIKE '$name'";
mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_affected_rows();

if ($num > 0) {
echo '1';
} else {
echo '0';
}
```

when I implement a test log on the SQL database, it somehow still seems to show up with spaces instead of underscores(even though I replace it in Java and PHP) and the PHP file returns '0' rather than '1'. I've heard the issue might be whitespaces? It seems to happen to only certain users, mostly mac users.

Comment: are you sure the string actually has spaces and not some other whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

If your php file is returning a 0, that means your query is not getting executed. Where are you establishing a connection with the database before executing the query?

Comment: No the connection does work, but for users with spaces in their names it will only work 50% of the time for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Remark: `where name = '$name'`

`mysql_affected_rows` concerns INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.

```
$r = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unsafe to pass raw name into URL without encoding it.

```
String urlString = "http://www.example.com/auth/verifyuser.php?name=" + URLEncoder.encode(name.toLowerCase(), "UTF-8");
```

In PHP you can obtain data:

```
$name = urldecode($_GET['name']);
```